# Can't make plain web service work in plain servlet [Netbeans, glassfish]

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I'm making 2 simple web projects: one with auto-generated webservice with only hello operation and second project with auto-generated servlet. Merging them into java ee app, then adding web service client to project with servlet. I'm calling web service in servlet and when I try to use hello method Glassfish gives me output:

```
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Warning:   wsdl file WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl does not exist for service-ref s.NewServlet/service
Warning:   wsdl file WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl does not exist for service-ref s.NewServlet/service
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [AppTest#ServletTest.war] at [ServletTest]
Info:   Loading application [AppTest#WebServiceTest.war] at [WebServiceTest]
Info:   AppTest was successfully deployed in 339 milliseconds.
Warning:   Context path from ServletContext: /ServletTest differs from path from bundle: ServletTest
Warning:   MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at file:/C:/Users/Michu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AppTest/dist/gfdeploy/AppTest/ServletTest_war/WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl using protocol SOAP_1_2. Continuing attempts.
Warning:   MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at file:/C:/Users/Michu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AppTest/dist/gfdeploy/AppTest/ServletTest_war/WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl using protocol SOAP_1_1. Continuing attempts.
Warning:   MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at file:/C:/Users/Michu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AppTest/dist/gfdeploy/AppTest/ServletTest_war/WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl/mex using protocol SOAP_1_2. Continuing attempts.
Warning:   MEX0008:Failed to parse metadata returned from server at file:/C:/Users/Michu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AppTest/dist/gfdeploy/AppTest/ServletTest_war/WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl/mex using protocol SOAP_1_1. Continuing attempts.
Info:   Going to fetch ServletAdapter holding wsdl content for web service NewWebService based on url: file:/C:/Users/Michu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AppTest/dist/gfdeploy/AppTest/ServletTest_war/WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl
Warning:   Following exception was thrown:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.initiateInstance(WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.resolveWSReference(WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$WebServiceRefProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:636)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:991)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: file:/C:/Users/Michu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AppTest/dist/gfdeploy/AppTest/ServletTest_war/WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl. It failed with: 
    C:\Users\Michu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AppTest\dist\gfdeploy\AppTest\ServletTest_war\WEB-INF\wsdl\localhost_8080\WebServiceTest\NewWebService.wsdl (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki).
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:265)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:364)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:208)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:119)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
    at t.NewWebService_Service.<init>(NewWebService_Service.java:58)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Michu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AppTest\dist\gfdeploy\AppTest\ServletTest_war\WEB-INF\wsdl\localhost_8080\WebServiceTest\NewWebService.wsdl (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:999)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:400)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
    ... 60 more

Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Marking servlet NewServlet as unavailable
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[NewServlet]: Allocate exception for servlet NewServlet
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Michu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AppTest\dist\gfdeploy\AppTest\ServletTest_war\WEB-INF\wsdl\localhost_8080\WebServiceTest\NewWebService.wsdl (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:999)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:400)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:364)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:208)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:119)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
    at t.NewWebService_Service.<init>(NewWebService_Service.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.initiateInstance(WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.resolveWSReference(WebServiceReferenceManagerImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$WebServiceRefProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:636)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:991)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Servlet:

```
package s;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import t.NewWebService_Service;

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl")
    private NewWebService_Service service;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println(hello("John")); //WEBSERVICE CALL
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    private String hello(java.lang.String name) {
        // Note that the injected javax.xml.ws.Service reference as well as port objects are not thread safe.
        // If the calling of port operations may lead to race condition some synchronization is required.
        t.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
        return port.hello(name);
    }
}
```

Webservice:

```
package t;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
public class NewWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="NewServlet" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Run!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki` translate to in English?

Comment: System can't find specified path.

Comment: I'm doing everything like in this tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

And still this same errors. I even redownloaded glassfish

Answer (score 0):

The java exception is stating the file does not exist at:

`C:\Users\Michu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AppTest\dist\gfdeploy\AppTest\ServletTest_war\WEB-INF\wsdl\localhost_8080\WebServiceTest\NewWebService.wsdl`

and:

`C:\Users\Michu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AppTest\dist\gfdeploy\AppTest\ServletTest_war\WEB-INF\wsdl\localhost_8080\WebServiceTest\NewWebService.wsdl`

So if this file doesn't exist you either need to have netbeans generate it for you [Netbeans Web Service](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html), or create it yourself using [wsgen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html).

Glassfish is also giving you the same warning:

`Warning:   wsdl file WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl does not exist for service-ref s.NewServlet/service
Warning:   wsdl file WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/WebServiceTest/NewWebService.wsdl does not exist for service-ref s.NewServlet/service`

Comment: Okay. When I manually make that wsdl file everything works :)
But why Netbeans can't do this for me??